# Spring @ExceptionHandler, how to preserve model attributes

Tags: spring, forms, spring-mvc, exception, model

Seems like `@ExceptionHandler` clears the model populated by the request handler that threw the exception. Consider the following scenario:

```
@Controller
public class GreetController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "form", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showForm(@ModelAttribute("userInfoFormObject") UserInfoForm form) {
        return "form";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "processform", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String processForm(@Valid @ModelAttribute("userInfoFormObject")   UserInfoForm form,
            BindingResult errors)
            throws RegisterFormException {

        if (errors.hasErrors())
            throw new RegisterFormException();

        return "greet";
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(RegisterFormException.class)
    public String registerFormException() {
        return "form";
    }

}
```

User inputs invalid data into a register form, `RegisterFormException` is thrown and `exception handler` takes user back to register form. Spring jstl tag library expects `UserInfoForm` object as an `model attribute`. However, `exception handler` creates new `empty model`. Is there way to preserve the `populated model` across `exception handler`, or is my only choice to return form view name in the request handler in the case of errors? Is the example solution considered as an anti pattern?

Comment: Pass the `UserInfoForm` to the exception constructor and use it in your `ExceptionHandler`s...

Comment: Don't throw an exception in the first place don't use exception for control flow.

Comment: What if I use dedicated @ModelAttribute annotated method to bind and validate UserInfoForm to model? Then throwing an exception is the only choice, as that method couldn't return a view name.